# Removing an element from a string

Tags: python, string

I have a specific problem concerning strings. I have a string which has a dollar sign and sometimes a comma. Basically I am scraping a number with selenium  and it can come in two forms:

1. `$257,873` (with comma)
2. `$257` (without comma)

How can I remove the comma only if there is one?

This is what I tried:

```
mc1 = (mc_txt.text).replace("$", "")

str = ""
for i in range(len(mc1)):
    if mc1[i] !=  ",":
        str = str + mc1[i]

mc = int(str)
print(mc)
```

Comment: Add a language tag and explain why your code is inadequate. You are OK with using `replace` once. Why not again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statment `(mc_txt.text).replace("$", "")` returns a string without any dollar signs. You can use the same trick to remove commas. In fact, since you are only trying to remove the leftmost dollar sign, a better option might be

```
mc = int(mc_txt.text.lstrip('$').replace(',', ''))
```

Here are a couple or examples using the REPL:

```
>>> '$123'.lstrip('$').replace(',', '')
'123'
>>> '$123,000'.lstrip('$').replace(',', '')
'123000'
>>> '123,000'.lstrip('$').replace(',', '')
'123000'
>>> '123'.lstrip('$').replace(',', '')
'123'
```

Comment: But that does not solve my problem. Because sometimes there is a comma and sometimes there is not. If there is not a comma, I will get an error.

Comment: @LaForge1071. No you won't. See update. I copy-pasted directly from the REPL